# How to Mark a detected victim in hector slam

Tags: slam, navigation, hector

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,
I want to know how i can mark a detected victim in map, using hector_slam...
can any one help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58328/how-to-mark-a-detected-victim-in-hector-slam/) by [alirezam.alizadeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4446/alirezam.alizadeh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-03-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Mapping objects of interest can be performed using the [hector_object_tracker](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_object_tracker) framework, which is independent of the SLAM system that is used to generate an environment map. It keeps track of objects of interest and using plugins for [hector_geotiff](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_geotiff), these can be added to generated geotiff maps.
We haven't added comprehensive documentation for that yet, but looking at a example setup might be enough. A simulation scenario can be started as described [here](https://code.google.com/p/irrw2012/wiki/RunningRescueScenarioSimulation). Note the [hlugv_worldmodel_all.launch](https://code.google.com/p/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/source/browse/trunk/hlugv_common/hlugv_apps/launch/hlugv_worldmodel_all.launch) that is launched there. This in turn launches the [object_tracker.launch](https://code.google.com/p/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/source/browse/trunk/hlugv_common/hlugv_apps/launch/object_tracker.launch) launch file, that sets up the object_tracker. A confirmed victim can then be added using a service call like in [this example](https://code.google.com/p/irrw2012/source/browse/trunk/rqt_rescue_control_plugin/lib/RescueControlDialog.py#59). When a GeoTiff map is saved, this added victim will also be plotted into it as the necessary plugins for doing that have been loaded using [hector_geotiff.launch](https://code.google.com/p/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/source/browse/trunk/hlugv_common/hlugv_apps/launch/hector_geotiff.launch).

/edit: Since this answer has been originally posted, the object_tracker has been renamed to hector_object_tracker, so this change will also have to be reflected in launch files using it.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alirezam.alizadeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4446/alirezam.alizadeh/) on 2013-03-18**:
Thank you for your response...
I will consider your notes as soon as possible and i will be grateful if i can help you in completing this part of documentation of tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Although not sure if this helps, and yet not available and for `GPS` only, I'm making an `rqt_gps`, an [rqt](http://ros.org/wiki/rqt) plugin that plots `GPS` positions. [Discussion about feature](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/issues/41) is happening and I'm planning to test with `hector`.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-03-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2013-03-18**:
We're currently only writing very basic information (see http://www.robocuprescue.org/wiki/images/GeoTiff.pdf) into the .tfw file associated with the .tif, so that probably will not be very useful for testing your GPS package.

**Comment by [Behzad.Mcki](https://answers.ros.org/users/51074/behzad.mcki/) on 2020-01-20**:
The links that you have  given is too OLD and its not working any more
please help me I have the same problem as he asked in 2020!!